# Throwing ClassNotFoundException due to deleted Target folder

Tags: java, maven, swing, netbeans, classnotfoundexception

I tried adding a dependency in my pom.xml, but turns out it is not what I am looking for so I deleted it in my pom.xml.

This is what I removed

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>Log_In</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I then tried the **Clean** option in my Maven project in NetBeans 13 as per what I saw in a tutorial and now I lost every subfolder in my **Target** folder including the folder where my **.class** files are located. And so my project is not running anymore and is throwing a ClassNotFoundException.

> Error: Could not find or load main class Log_In Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Log_In Command execution failed.
> org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an
> error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
> at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
> at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
> at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:982)
> at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:929)
> at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:457)
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
> (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:577)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
> (Launcher.java:282)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
> (Launcher.java:406)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ BUILD FAILURE
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Total time:  4.991 s Finished at: 2022-09-15T16:33:12+08:00
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec
> (default-cli) on project Hotel_Management_System: Command execution
> failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
> switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

I'm completely aware that this is my fault for not reading a documentation beforehand. Please help me, any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Did you try `mvn compile` to recompile again?

Comment: @Chaosfire Thank you very much! You just solve my over 2 days problem, I've actually tried many things and watched countless tutorial, but nothing works out. I don't know about `mvn compile` so I research about it first. I'm new to java so I'm still struggling to cope up. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Check [maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) about the lifecycle. All phases are explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its completely okay during maven build process to delete and recreate the target folder.

You only lost *generated* class files. Your source files (.java) should still exist and if you run a full `mvn clean install` they will be recompiled and your target folder, .class files and jar assets recreated.